# SQL count return codes by date

Tags: sql, count, pivot

I'm stuck with the question: how many return codes of different types do I have per day.
So I have to transform this input data:

```
Date    Code
17JAN2016   200
17JAN2016   200
17JAN2016   200
17JAN2016   210
16JAN2016   230
16JAN2016   230
16JAN2016   230
```

into something like this:

```
        17JAN2016   16JAN2016
200     4           null
210     1           null
230     null        3
240     null        null
```

I'll appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `CASE` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select code,
       count(case when Date = '17JAN2016' then 1 end) as "17JAN2016",
       count(case when Date = '16JAN2016' then 1 end) as "16JAN2016"
from tablename
group by code
```

**Notes:**

1. The date comparisons may need to be adjusted depending on dbms product (and column data type.)
2. `date` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit it as `"date"`. (Just like the column aliases starting with digits.)